# Return Latitude and Longitude from an address

Tags: geolocation

I have a list of a couple thousand addresses and I would like to find the Longitude and Latitude of each one. I know I can use websites such as google maps to individually search the geolocations, but I would like to know how to make one massive input of all the addresses(such as putting them all in one array) and get an array that returns the Longitude and Latitude of each in perhaps a corresponding array. 
I know Java fairly well but no other languages. 
I would prefer detailed instructions or coding that would allow me to do the actions described above.

Thank You

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please start by searching. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18282375/php-geolocation-street-address-lat-long

Answer (score 0):

The company I work for has an Excel plug-in for address geocoding, no programming required:

https://www.yaddress.net/Home/Excel

Answer (score 0):

SmartyStreets (disclaimer: I work for them) has a list tool specifically built for excel style address data. You can easily paste in your excel data of addresses and the list tool will verify each address as well as return information like the latitude and longitude. You can try it out [here](https://smartystreets.com/list-demo).